Derivative using torch.fft oscilates on the boundary
I was trying to use the torch.fft to compute derivatives. The issue is that even for a simple example ($f = \sin(x)$), I have weird oscillations on the boundaries.
Is there an issue in the following code, or is there a problem with torch.fft (or, more probably, how I use it)?
Thanks
import torch
import torch.fft

# Define the number of sample points and the domain
n = 1024
x = torch.linspace(0, 2 * torch.pi, n)
# Define the function f(x) = sin(x)
f_x = torch.sin(x)
# Compute the FFT of the function
F_k = torch.fft.fft(f_x)
# Define the frequencies
k = torch.fft.fftfreq(n, d=(2 * torch.pi / n))
# Compute the  derivative
derivative_fft = 1j * 2 * torch.pi * k * F_k
# Compute the inverse FFT to get the derivative in the time domain
df_x = torch.fft.ifft(derivative_fft).real
# The real part is taken as the result since the input is real-valued
# Print the original function and its derivative
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(x, f_x, label='f(x) = sin(x)')
plt.plot(x, df_x, label="f'(x) = cos(x)", linestyle='dashed')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.title('Function and its Derivative using FFT')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()



EDIT:
I should be more precise. When I use the fft from numpy I see no oscillation:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the function to be differentiated
def f(x):
    return np.sin(x)

# Number of sample points
N = 1024
# Sampling interval
L = 2 * np.pi
x = np.linspace(0, L, N, endpoint=False)
y = f(x)

# FFT of the function
y_fft = np.fft.fft(y)

# Frequency components
k = np.fft.fftfreq(N, L / N) * 2 * np.pi

# Differentiation in the frequency domain (multiply by i*k)
y_fft_derivative = 1j * k * y_fft

# Inverse FFT to get back to the spatial domain
y_derivative = np.fft.ifft(y_fft_derivative)

# The imaginary part should be very close to zero
y_derivative_real = np.real(y_derivative)

# Exact derivative of sin(x)
exact_derivative = np.cos(x)

# Plot the results
plt.plot(x, y_derivative_real, label='FFT Derivative')
plt.plot(x, exact_derivative, label='Exact Derivative', linestyle='--')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('Derivative')
plt.title('Derivative of sin(x) using FFT')
plt.show()




Does this answer your question? Taking derivative using FFT

Replace
x = torch.linspace(0, 2 * torch.pi, n)

with
dx = 2 * torch.pi / n
x = torch.linspace(0, 2 * torch.pi - dx, n)

I think the code needs no further explanation.

